# How to turn an array of objects into a (larger) array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have this array of objects that I want to turn into an array of strings. Is there a simple way to do it?

```js
var obj = [
  {firstName: "Daniel", lastName: "James"},
  {firstName: "Laura", lastName: "Murray"}
];
```

To

```js
var obj = ["Daniel", "James", "Laura", "Murray"]
```

Comment: what is a string array? please add the result as well, along with your try.

Comment: `Is there a simple way to do it?` Nope, because there is no concept like `string array`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to coding. You're mean!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list by mapping a function over each item of a list.

Example: `y` is created by mapping `n => n + 1` over each item of `x`:

```js
const x = [10, 20, 30];
const y = x.map(n => n + 1);

x;
//=> [10, 20, 30]

y;
//=> [11, 21, 31]
```

You can also turn a list of things into a list of other things: `x` is a list of numbers and `y` is a list of strings.

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3];
const y = x.map(n => ''.repeat(n));

y;
//=> ["", "", ""]
```

In your case you need to turn a list of *n* objects into a list of *n × 2* strings. (Each object "producing" two strings; a first name and a last name)

For this we need to use `Array#flatMap` which map a function over each item of a list *and* flatten the result of the function into the new list.

A simple example will make this all clear:

```js
const x = ['', ''];
const y = x.flatMap(n => [n, n]);

y;
//=> ["", "", "", ""]
```

Now let's solve your issue!

```js
const y = x.flatMap(({firstName, lastName}) => [firstName, lastName]);

console.log(y);
```

```html
<script>
const x =
  [ { firstName: "Daniel"
    , lastName: "James"
    }
    ,
    { firstName: "Laura"
    , lastName: "Murray"
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that an array of all values is the objective.

This is the structure of an array of objects:

```
let data = [ //(begin array)
  { //(begin first object)
    firstName: /*(key or property)*/ "Jon", /*(VALUE) what you want*/
    lastName: /*(key or property)*/ "Doe" /*(VALUE) what you want*/
  }, //(end first object)
  //... (more objects, etc)
]; //(end array)
```

1. Apply [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method which is [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) combined

   - It runs a function on each object then flattens the return if it is an array
2. The callback function within `.flatMap()` should be able to extract the values from each object within the array of objects.

   - For this phase use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which returns an array of values of a given object.
3. Each method returns a result as follows:

   1. `Object.values()` each return will be from: `{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}` to `["value1", "value2"]`
   2. If `.map()` was used then the final return would be: `[["value1", "value2"], ...]` an array of arrays.
   3. If `.flat()` was applied to the result of **#2** the return would be: `["value1", "value2", ...]`
   4. `.flatMap()` does both **#2** and **#3**.

The demo below features a custom function: `getvalues()`. Pass in an array of objects and it returns an array of all the values of each object. The advantage using this function over other code used in the other answers is that the actual key (aka property) doesn't have to be known and the amount of key/value pairs within each object doesn't matter. So an input of:

```
let data = [
  {firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Doe", age: 30}, 
  {first: "Jane", last: "Doe"}, 
  {color: "green"}
];
```

is valid as well.

---

### Demo

```js
let data = [
  {first: "Daniel", last: "James"},
  {first: "Laura", last: "Murray"}
];

const getValues = arrayOfObjects => arrayOfObjects.flatMap(object => Object.values(object));

console.log(getValues(data));
```